# How does a proton behave when placed in a uniform electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

If a proton is held at rest in a region with a uniform electric field and then released, will the proton follow the field line? Or can it cross other lines?

I think the proton will only follow one line, depending on whether its charge is positive or negative, but I don't know if that's true, so I would like to know how it will behave.

Comment: Does the proton have an initial velocity? What does "stops released" mean?

Comment: I meant that the proton is placed, then It is released with no initial velocity.

Comment: Probably you mean a classical test charge, which does not involve quantum mechanics and spin

Answer (score 1):

The equation of motion is:

$$m\frac{\partial^2 \vec x(t)}{\partial t^2} = q\vec E(\vec x)$$

If the field is uniform ($z$-direction), then:

$$ \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = 0$$
$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = 0$$
$$ \frac{d^2 z}{dt^2} = \frac{qE}m$$

The solutions are:

$$ x(t) = x_0+v_xt$$
$$ y(t) = y_0+v_yt$$
$$ z(t) = z_0+v_zt+\frac 1 2  +\frac{qE}m t^2$$

The stipulation that $(v_x,v_y,v_z)=(0,0,0)$ means:

$$ x(t) = x_0$$
$$ y(t) = y_0$$
$$ z(t) = z_0+\frac{qE}{2m} t^2$$

or:

$$ \vec x(t) = \vec x_0 + \frac{qE}{2m} t^2 \hat z $$

The tangent vector to that path is:

$$ \dot{\vec x}(t) = \frac{qE}{m} t \hat z =\frac{q}{m}t\vec E$$

which follows a field line.

Answer (score 0):

For a uniform electric field the field lines are straight, parallel and uniformly spaced. So there are no "other lines" to cross.

A positive test charge released from rest at any point in the uniform electric field will experience a constant force in the direction of the electric field lines. A negative charge (electron) will do the same, only the direction of the force it will experience is opposite to the direction of the field lines.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The proton will not follow a single field line.  because the proton has *mass*, its inertia will provide a "resistance" to acceleration.

Imagine a situation where the field lines initially point to the right, but then curve upward.  We place the proton in a region where the field lines point to the right, so the proton begins accelerating to the right until it has some velocity to the right. Then the field lines curve upward, so the force is now pointing upward. But the proton is moving already to the right, so it will continue to cross field lines unless there is some other force that pushes it to the left.

Comment: He said "uniform electric field". The lines do not curve for uniform field.